# Extract a value from database field to checkbox value PHP

Tags: javascript, html

I am using HTML and PHP for this scenario, the code follows :

```
echo"<td>".'<div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="total" id ="total" value="'.$test['req_tot'].'" " onchange="checkTotal()">'.$test['req_tot'].'
              </label>
            </div>'."</td>";
```

Javascript:

```
 function checkTotal() {
      alert(document.getElementById("total.value"));
    }
```

Now, when I click the checkbox, instead of displaying the value `$test['req_tot']` from database it shows NULL[image]

*N.B :- Values form database are being displayed properly*

Comment: Shouldn't it be `alert(document.getElementById("total").value)`? I see no element named `total.value`, if you do have that element you still need to `value` selector to get the value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: how to get value of text input field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/javascript-how-to-get-value-of-text-input-field)

Comment: your edited comment is correct not the `.value()`, anyways thanks though

Comment: Yea, I'm not much of a JSer, PHP tag brought me. I usually jQuery which is why I put that first (although in jquery it was wrong too `val()`).

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript is not correct.

```
function checkTotal() {
          alert(document.getElementById("total").value);
        }
```